# What are the rules for deciding when a new catalog should be created?

Tags: plone

I'd like to learn about using catalogs correctly.

I have about 30 useful content types, about 50 indexes in catalog.xml, and about 45 metadatas.  There are just three types which account for most of the site's data - and I may need millions of these.  I've been reading, and there's lots to do, but I want to have the basic configuration right before I begin all that.

[This page](http://toutpt.wordpress.com/2008/12/14/archetype_tool-queuecatalog-becareful-with-indexing-with-plones-portal_catalog/) told me that any non-default indexes should not be added to the portal_catalog.  I've even read people explaining how removing one, or two of the default indexes makes a performance difference.

My question is: what are the rules for dividing up the indexes into different catalogs, and for selecting which catalog(s) index which type(s)?

So far I have created one additional catalog, used to catalog all indexes for my 'site-setup' objects (which I have caused to no longer be indexed in portal_catalog).  The site-setup indexes are very often used, but more rarely modified than others, so I thought it was correct to separate them from objects which are reindexed more often.  I'm not sure if that's the main consideration though.

Another similar question (a good example of the kind of thing I want to solve): how would you handle something like secondary workflow review_state variables?  I give each workflow's review_state variable an index (and search on them quite often), but some of my workflows are only used on just a few types.  (my most prolific objects have secondary workflows...)

I'd be very grateful for advice!

Campbell

Answer (score 3):

This won't cover everything but I'll bring up some points..

Anything not in the portal_catalog won't work with collections, folder_contents view, getFolderContents method, search, portlet collections, related items(I think) and anything else the assumes you're using the portal_catalog.

I like to use an additional catalog when I need to be able to query the data but it only affects a sub-set of the content objects.

Use collective.indexing to speed up indexing operations.

Mount the catalogs on their own mount points so you can cache them differently from the rest of the site(so you can cache the whole catalog). Then, you can even serve the the catalogs from dedicated zeoserver.

Also, if your content doesn't have to be cataloged by the portal_catalog(with all the constraints listed), you may even want to think about if you need it as a full-fledged (archetype|dexterity) type in the first place.  You can use a more slim repoze.catalog to catalog arbitrary objects(which could be very simple data) for whatever your purpose is and get even more performance. Or better yet, look into Solr for indexing it for VERY good performance.

On more thing, depending on the type of data you're storing, you could even look into using a relational database for a data store. But I don't know what kind of queries, indexes, data, etc you have...

30 different types seems like a lot but I don't know what your use case is. Care to share? Perhaps there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I've been working on [This](https://github.com/bikalabs/Bika-LIMS).  The most numerous objects are of type [Analysis](https://github.com/bikalabs/Bika-LIMS/blob/master/bika/lims/content/analysis.py), which is pretty heavy, it seems to me...  What you see there are relics of code which comes from Plone 2 (and probably even earlier).